# load command in matlab loading blank file

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am loading a file in matlab, but it is being loaded as an empty variable.

```
positive    0x0    []
```

and am using

```
 load positive.txt
```

but the file is not empty. Is the something am wrong?
P.S. I have loaded other files from the same folder successfully. Also I tried to rename it to positive.dat but that also didn't work. And it was an excel file that I saved as an text file.

and the first couple entries of the file, copied & pasted

```
04  10  19
04  10  36
04  10  28
04  16  16
04  14  01
04  20  21
04  20  06
04  20  28
04  13  14
04  13  17
04  13  02
04  01  16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load` command is only for MAT-files (file extension `.mat`) or ASCII files saved in MATLAB format, usually in MATLAB using `save` command. For all other file formats you should use some other command.

For text files you can use `fopen`, `fscanf`, `fclose`. For binary files you can use `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose`. `fopen` opens the file for reading and/or writing, `fscanf` or `fread` read data from file (`fscanf` reads text, `fread` binary data) and then `fclose` closes the file.

For Excel files you can use `xlsread`. `xlsread` does not need `fopen` or `fclose`.