# How to load data for Classification in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file containing thousands of attributes (each column indicates an attribute) and a column that shows the labels of each row.All data is numeric except the last column which is the labels. This column is string. I want to use matlab classification functions such as gscatter() to classify the data. The problem is that when I use load filename in matlab to load my data I get this error (in which "no" is one of the lables)

Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\train\train.txt
"no".

In fact I do not know how to load my data in matlab to be able to use matlab functions to classify the data.

Comment: Related to [load command in matlab loading blank file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337828/load-command-in-matlab-loading-blank-file/10337947#10337947).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

#### train.txt

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,no
2,3,4,5,6,7,yes
```

#### myLoadScript.m

```
numAttribs = 6;        %# number of attributes (excluding the label)
frmt = [repmat('%f ',1,numAttribs) '%s'];
fid = fopen('train.txt', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);
```

The result:

```
>> C{1}
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     2     3     4     5     6     7

>> C{2}
ans = 
    'no'
    'yes'
```

Should be easy to adapt to work on your specific file format...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now, is it possible to divide this set of data to train and test?

Answer (score 2):

[Load](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) is only for .mat files and text files with only numeric data, which is why you get an error.

There are a number of functions which do read text files though. 
Depending on the format of your data files, you could use one of the following:

- [textread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html) is pretty general but requires you to supply the format and to open and close the file.
- [csvread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html) reads only numeric, comma-separated value, but you don't have to provide a format.
- [importdata](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) is very general and convenient
- [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html) is similar to textread

Given the number of attributes you're dealing with, I'd definitely go with `importdata` myself.

Comment: Load can be used for text files as well, as long as they contain only a matrix of numbers.