# convert multiple .txt to multiple ascii files fast - possible in Matlab?

Tags: macos, matlab, file-io, text-files

I have over 120 .txt files (all named like s1.txt, s2.txt, ..., s120.txt) that I need to convert to ASCII extension to use in MATLAB.

```
my .txt (comma , delimited .txt) files look like the following:
20080102,43.0300,3,9.493,569.567,34174.027,34174027
20080102,43.0600,3,9.498,569.897,34193.801,34193801
```

In MATLAB I wish to use code similar to the following:

```
for i = svec; 
   %# where svec = [1 2 13 15] some random number between 1 and 120. 
   eval(['load %mydirectory', eval(['s',int2str(i)]),'.ascii']);
end;
```

If I am not mistaken I can't use the above command with .txt files and therefore I must use ASCII files.

Since I have a lot of files to convert and they are large in size, is there a quick way to convert all my files via MATLAB, or perhaps there is a great converting software available for Mac on the web? Would anyone have a better suggestion than using the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to nrz's answer:

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but know that you can open any file in MATLAB, both as text (ASCII) or in binary mode. The latter can be achieved using [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html).

As a side note, you also asked for a better suggestion for your code.
Well, what did you try to achieve with the two `eval` invocations? Why not call the commands directly? Do this instead:

```
for i = svec
   load (['%mydirectory\s', int2str(i), '.txt'], '-ascii');
end
```

I also took the liberty to add a backslash that I think you had omitted.

In most cases, you'd be better off without using `eval`. Check the [alternatives](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqy1gs-2.html#brqy1gs-3)...

Comment: Can I simply do the following for .txt? `for i = svec; 
   load (['%mydirectory\s', int2str(i), '.txt']);
end;`

Comment: It would work if your file is an ASCII MAT-file, but I added the `'-ascii'` switch to the `load` command, to force loading the file as ASCII regardless of the extension.

Comment: Also, I didn't notice until now that you put `;`s after your `for` and `end`. Lose them.

Comment: @EitanT: it is still valid syntax (I mean the `;` after the for/end)

Comment: @Amro I know, you could also put `;;;;;` after that and that would still be valid. But it's just inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show an example file? Not every text file is valid for `load` command. If your file is not in a valid format, changing the extension part of filename from `.txt` to `.ascii` doesn't help at all. Instead, in that case the data must be either converted to a valid format for `load` command or, alternatively, loaded into MATLAB by some other means eg. by using `fscanf` or `xlsread`. File structure is needed for both ways to solve this.

See also [load command in matlab loading blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337828/load-command-in-matlab-loading-blank-file).

Comment: see above for my .txt file example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner way:

```
for i=1:120
    fname = fullfile('mydirectory', sprintf('s%d.txt',i));
    X = load(fname, '-ascii');
end
```

Comment: what's the real benefit to load my data in ascii or .txt? I am  trying to figure out the easiest way to load various multiple dataset at once and then for each datasets (in a loop) to some math functions etc... I always I thought I had to use ascii file to load various dataset at once. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesMartineau: Just so that you understand, the `'-ascii'` part above refers to a special mode of the LOAD/SAVE functions that deal with plain text files, instead of the default MAT files (which are MATLAB's own binary format for storing data). It has nothing to do with the file name extension

Comment: @Amro: strike that, LOAD actually accepts any of the following as separator: blank, comma, semicolon, or tab character. The only condition is that the data has to be a 2D rectangular table of numbers. Sorry, one should always refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html#inputarg_%27-ascii%27) :)

Comment: I tried your code but say that I have a vector `svec = [44 46] %where 44 and 56 corresponds to txt file s44 and s46 and let snum=length(svec);` I want to load both files separately because once they are loaded I intend to use this loop `for j=1:snum;
i=svec(j); %additional command below end;` Should I modify your code as follow: `for i=svec;
    fname = fullfile('mydirectory', sprintf('s%d.txt',i));
    X = load(fname, '-ascii');
end` I have the impression that only the last file gets loaded. Thanks!

Comment: my bad... if I use the code of Eitan it works to separate my datasets and then use the following `for j=1:snum;
i=svec(j);

data=eval(['s',int2str(i)]); #more math command..... end;`. Thanks again for the help!